# Adding extra info via GET while registeration in wordpress

Tags: customization, user-registration

i am trying to make a little referral sort of system for my site. so for that i settuped an extra parameter in the registeration url as :

www.domain.com/wp-login.php?action=register`&register_me=site_name`

and one is adding ip address while registeration, at first i thought it would be a simple form in wp-login.php but i just found out its all based on filters etc.. very complicated stuff.

I did setuped two extra fields in the wp_user table. called `'reg_ip' and 'referral'` ..

now i need to understand how to add these two things in wp-login.php so they will be inserted in teh database while registeration.

Help is really really appreciated :) 
cheers
Ayaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently written an affiliate plugin where i had to do pretty much the same stuff. Here's a chopup of the relevant parts:

To process the extra info you get from the registration form:

```
add_action('user_register', 'my_handle_signup', 10, 2);

function my_handle_signup($user_id, $data = null) {
    $reg_ip = $_REQUEST['reg_ip'];
    $referrer = $_REQUEST['referrer'];
    if (isset($reg_ip) && isset($referrer)) {
        add_user_meta($user_id, 'my_referrer', $referrer);
        add_user_meta($user_id, 'my_reg_ip', $reg_ip);
    }
}
```

And to add fields to the signup form:

```
add_action('register_form', 'my_add_signup_fields');

function my_add_signup_fields() {
    if (!empty($_GET['register_me'])) {
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="reg_ip" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_GET['register_me']); ?>" />
        <?php
    }
}
```

For my solution, i'm actually setting a cookie and then retrieving that on the registration form.

Comment: hey , im absolute newbie, so considering your code i got a bit confused that where will i put my referal value which is coming from $_GET['register_me'] and the ip will be taken by : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; . can u please edit the above code by fitting these in so i can atleast get the idea how wordpress filters actually work. thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: done

Comment: Do you really write user generated data unescaped into the table and the markup? Dangerous!

Comment: @toscho do wordpress has its own protection function which i can use here ? 
@wyrfel thank you so much my friend.

Comment: @Wyfrel, bro i put it as it is, and yes i do have both rows in wp_user table  'reg_ip' and 'refferal' but it seems that it don't insert the data on registeration. any ideas what can be wrong ?

Comment: @Ayaz Malik See http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: @toscho , so in my case it would be like this right : $wpdb->escape( $_GET['...'] ) right?

Comment: @Wyfrel, oh so as i see it is added in the user_meta instad. k kool. so i can just cal them as current_user->reg_ip ? right

Comment: @Ayaz Malik I’d rather use `$wpdb->prepare()` for DB inserts and esc_* for output.

Comment: @toscho: `add_user_meta()` uses `$wpdb->prepare()` implicitly (apart from the fact that the values get serialized), so if you recommend using `$wpdb->prepare()` in this context without mentioning that, it may get a bit confusing, don't you think?

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: No, you can't access it as `$current_user->reg_ip`, but you can recall it with `get_user_meta($user_id, 'my_referrals', true)`. And if it doesn't insert the data, you might need to check if it comes through to `my_handle_signup()`. Or before that, check if the hidden fields appear in your registration form.

Comment: @wyrfel You’re right. `prepare()` is called in `add_metadata()`.

Comment: @wyrfel but like this it will lose the concept of me driving the count of registerations via same referal / domain ... and display it for that domain/referal guy's account in the custom account page. or there is a way around that ? i mean if i can get all the referals count which have referral = xxxdomain.com .. ? that is why i wanted to add those in the wp_user table directly so it would be easier for me to use simple queries and drive them out where needed.

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: You don't add stuff directly to `wp_users`. I edited the example above to store two separate meta values which will make it easier for you to do meta queries against them or count the records. Please read up on how to query/count meta data (google for it).

Comment: K thanks im going to give it a try. just curious why we can't add in wp_users ?

Comment: Because it's not your table. ;-) It's bad practice to add columns to a core wp table as there's chances your columns won't survive updates or may confuse WP on updates. Also, adding columns to the tables would mean you'd have to write your own SQL for everything and can't use the wp-native query functions which do all the sanitization etc. for you.

Comment: aah ok . makes sense. thx for the help lets hope i will get my way around with this code coz im new to these things.

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: Thanks for voting. Remember you only get less 'new to these things' by digging through them. And while WP code can be a bit entangled, it isn't that hard to read, actually.

Comment: thanks :) yes i tried a few other stuff as well.. i made a custom member area , profile area etc. wasn't that hard with the direct sqls with me heheeh, but im new to coding so goign to take a while with the filters i guess. i was digging a little and found out that if i make a custom new table in my dtabase then i don't have to worry about data deletion on upgrading wordpres, right ?

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: If you create your own table you have to worry about other things, though...like data consistency. Imagine someone deletes a user in WP that has an associated record in your table. If you don't add extra measures, you'll have a record with broken relationship. All of this is taken care of if you use metadata. So if you can, use metadata...it will survive updates and even the export/import routines.

Comment: hmm k yes makes senes, bro can i get in touch with you on IM or twitter maybe ? if you feel comfortable