# Checkboxes in registration form

Tags: custom-field

I want to use checkboxes on registration form, but values are not storing in the profile page.

here is the code on functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

<h3>Settori di interesse</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_silos" id="user_silos" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_silos", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_silos">Silos</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_biodigestori" id="user_biodigestori" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_biodigestori", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_biodigestori">Biodigestori</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_unitratt" id="user_unitratt" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_unitratt", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_unitratt">Unità di trattamento</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_imt" id="user_imt" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_imt", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_imt">Impianti di media tensione</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_cabelet" id="user_cabelet" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_cabelet", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_cabelet">Cabine elettriche</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_zoot" id="user_zoot" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_zoot", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_zoot">Zootecnica</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php }?>


<?php
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if (!isset($_POST['user_silos'])) $_POST['user_silos'] = "false"; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_silos', $_POST['user_silos'] );
    if (!isset($_POST['user_biodigestori'])) $_POST['user_biodigestori'] = "false"; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_biodigestori', $_POST['user_biodigestori'] );
    if (!isset($_POST['user_unitratt'])) $_POST['user_unitratt'] = "false"; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_unitratt', $_POST['user_unitratt'] );
    if (!isset($_POST['user_imt'])) $_POST['user_imt'] = "false"; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_imt', $_POST['user_imt'] );
    if (!isset($_POST['user_cabelet'])) $_POST['user_cabelet'] = "false"; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_cabelet', $_POST['user_cabelet'] );
    if (!isset($_POST['user_zoot'])) $_POST['user_zoot'] = "false"; 
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_zoot', $_POST['user_zoot'] );     
}
?>
```

on the registration page I have this code

```
 <div class="reg-row">
    <span class="ckb">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_silos" id="user_silos" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_silos", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
        <label for="user_silos">Silos</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ckb">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_biodigestori" id="user_biodigestori" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_biodigestori", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
        <label for="user_biodigestori">Biodigestori</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ckb">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_unitratt" id="user_unitratt" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_unitratt", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
        <label for="user_unitratt">Unità di trattamento</label>
    </span>
 </div> 

 <div class="reg-row">
    <span class="ckb">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_imt" id="user_imt" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_imt", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
        <label for="user_imt">Impianti di media tensione</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ckb">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_cabelet" id="user_cabelet" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_cabelet", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
        <label for="user_cabelet">Cabine elettriche</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ckb">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_zoot" id="user_zoot" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_zoot", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
        <label for="user_zoot">Zootecnia</label>
    </span>
 </div>
```

Does anyone know where I'm wrong? thanks for the help

---

EDIT

With multiple checkboxes it doesn't work...

If during the registration there aren't selections, on the profile page the checkboxes are all selected.

```
<?php

add_action( 'register_form', 'signup_fields_ckb' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'handle_signup_ckb', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'user_field_ckb' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'user_field_ckb' );

function signup_fields_ckb() {
?>

    <p class="txt-green">Settore di interesse</p>

     <div class="reg-row">
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_silos" id="user_silos" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_silos", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_silos">Silos</label>
        </span>
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_biodigestori" id="user_biodigestori" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_biodigestori", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_biodigestori">Biodigestori</label>
        </span>
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_unitratt" id="user_unitratt" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_unitratt", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_unitratt">Unità di trattamento</label>
        </span>
     </div> 

     <div class="reg-row">
        <span class="ckb ckb-imt">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_imt" id="user_imt" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_imt", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_imt">Impianti di media tensione</label>
        </span>
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_cabelet" id="user_cabelet" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_cabelet", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_cabelet">Cabine elettriche</label>
        </span>
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_cooger" id="user_cooger" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_cooger", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_cooger">Coogeneratori</label>
        </span>
     </div>  

     <div class="reg-row">
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_zoot" id="user_zoot" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_zoot", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_zoot">Zootecnica</label>
        </span>
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_attagri" id="user_attagri" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_attagri", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_attagri">Attrezzature Agricole</label>
        </span>
        <span class="ckb">
            <input type="checkbox" name="user_agriwat" id="user_agriwat" value="true" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "user_agriwat", $user->ID )) == "true") echo "checked"; ?> />
            <label for="user_agriwat">Agri Water</label>
        </span>
     </div>

<?php
}

function handle_signup_ckb( $user_id, $data = null ) 
{
    $user_silos = $_REQUEST['user_silos'];
    $user_biodigestori = $_REQUEST['user_biodigestori'];
    $user_unitratt = $_REQUEST['user_unitratt'];
    $user_imt = $_REQUEST['user_imt'];
    $user_cabelet = $_REQUEST['user_cabelet'];
    $user_cooger = $_REQUEST['user_cooger'];
    $user_zoot = $_REQUEST['user_zoot'];
    $user_attagri = $_REQUEST['user_attagri'];
    $user_silos = $_REQUEST['user_agriwat'];

    if ( isset( $user_silos ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_silos', $user_silos );}
    if ( isset( $user_biodigestori ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_biodigestori', $user_biodigestori );}
    if ( isset( $user_unitratt ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_unitratt', $user_unitratt );}
    if ( isset( $user_imt ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_imt', $user_imt );}
    if ( isset( $user_cabelet ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_cabelet', $user_cabelet );}
    if ( isset( $user_cooger ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_cooger', $user_cooger );}
    if ( isset( $user_zoot ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_zoot', $user_zoot );}
    if ( isset( $user_attagri ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_attagri', $user_attagri );}
    if ( isset( $user_agriwat ) ) { add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_agriwat', $user_agriwat );}
}



function user_field_ckb( $user ) 
{
    $user_silos = get_the_author_meta( 'user_silos', $user->ID );
    $user_biodigestori = get_the_author_meta( 'user_biodigestori', $user->ID );
    $user_unitratt = get_the_author_meta( 'user_unitratt', $user->ID );
    $user_imt = get_the_author_meta( 'user_imt', $user->ID );
    $user_cabelet = get_the_author_meta( 'user_cabelet', $user->ID );
    $user_cooger = get_the_author_meta( 'user_cooger', $user->ID );
    $user_zoot = get_the_author_meta( 'user_zoot', $user->ID );
    $user_attagri = get_the_author_meta( 'user_attagri', $user->ID );
    $user_silos = get_the_author_meta( 'user_agriwat', $user->ID );
?>

    <table class="form-table">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Silos'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_silos" id="user_silos" %1$s />', checked( $user_silos, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Biodigestori'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_biodigestori" id="user_biodigestori" %1$s />', checked( $user_biodigestori, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Unità di trattamento'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_unitratt" id="user_unitratt" %1$s />', checked( $user_unitratt, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Impianti di media tensione'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_imt" id="user_imt" %1$s />', checked( $user_imt, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Cabine elettriche'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_cabelet" id="user_cabelet" %1$s />', checked( $user_cabelet, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Coogeneratori'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_cooger" id="user_cooger" %1$s />', checked( $user_cooger, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Zootecnica'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_zoot" id="user_zoot" %1$s />', checked( $user_zoot, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Attrezzature agricole'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_attagri" id="user_attagri" %1$s />', checked( $user_attagri, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
          <td><span class="description"><?php _e('Agriwater'); ?></span><br>
          <label><?php printf('<input type="checkbox" name="user_agriwat" id="user_agriwat" %1$s />', checked( $user_agriwat, '', false ));?></label>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of creating a [custom registration page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22custom+registration%22), there are not much hooks that can be used to add custom fields to the default form. I tried once (with `register_form` hook) and only default fields (description, website, etc) were successfully recognized and saved.

Found this Q&A that has a workaround: [Adding extra info via GET while registeration in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/11193/12615)

Here's a proof of concept:

```
// REGISTRATION
add_action( 'register_form', 'signup_fields_wpse_87261' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'handle_signup_wpse_87261', 10, 2 );

// PROFILE
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'user_field_wpse_87261' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_profile_fields_87261' );

// USER EDIT
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'user_field_wpse_87261' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_profile_fields_87261' );

function signup_fields_wpse_87261() {
?>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom_feature_a" id="custom_feature_a" /> 
        Enable feature A?
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom_feature_b" id="custom_feature_b" /> 
        Enable feature B?
    </label>
    <hr />
<?php
}

function handle_signup_wpse_87261( $user_id, $data = null ) 
{
    $feat_a = isset( $_POST['custom_feature_a'] ) ? $_POST['custom_feature_a'] : false;
    $feat_b = isset( $_POST['custom_feature_b'] ) ? $_POST['custom_feature_b'] : false;
    if ( $feat_a ) 
    {
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_feature_a', $feat_a );
    }
    if ( $feat_b ) 
    {
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_feature_b', $feat_b );
    }
}

function user_field_wpse_87261( $user ) 
{
    $feat_a = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'custom_feature_a', true );
    $feat_b = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'custom_feature_b', true );
?>
    <h3><?php _e('Custom Fields'); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><?php 
                    printf(
                        '<input type="checkbox" name="custom_feature_a" id="custom_feature_a" %1$s />',
                        checked( $feat_a, 'on', false )
                    );
                    ?>
                    <span class="description"><?php _e('Custom Feature A?'); ?></span>
                    </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><?php 
                    printf(
                        '<input type="checkbox" name="custom_feature_b" id="custom_feature_b" %1$s />',
                        checked( $feat_b, 'on', false )
                    );
                    ?>
                    <span class="description"><?php _e('Custom Feature B?'); ?></span>
                    </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php 
}

function save_profile_fields_87261( $user_id ) 
{
    $feat_a = isset( $_POST['custom_feature_a'] ) ? $_POST['custom_feature_a'] : false;
    $feat_b = isset( $_POST['custom_feature_b'] ) ? $_POST['custom_feature_b'] : false;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'custom_feature_a', $feat_a );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'custom_feature_b', $feat_b );
}
```

Comment: doesn't work with multiple chekboxes

Comment: I've corrected the code but it still doesn't work.. now are all unselected. (ps. Even changing the checkbox in the profile values ​​are not stored)

Comment: @Epaxido, code revised and updated, working with two fields now.

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo ..works great! I think this will be useful for many people.