# How to display custom user meta from registration in backend?

Tags: users, user-meta, user-registration

I'm considering using the hooks for the WordPress registration form to add some custom fields: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

My question is, if it's even possible, how do I display some of these custom fields in the backend Users > All Users? For example if I have fields for 'zip code' and 'address', how would I display this data in the backend? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I found this to be more strait forward and simpler:

```
//add columns to User panel list page
function add_user_columns($column) {
    $column['address'] = 'Street Address';
    $column['zipcode'] = 'Zip Code';

    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_user_columns' );

//add the data
function add_user_column_data( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'address' :
            return $user->address;
            break;
        default:
    }
    return;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_user_column_data', 10, 3 );
```

More info for hooks for custom columns can be found here: http://tareq.wedevs.com/2011/07/add-your-custom-columns-to-wordpress-admin-panel-tables/

Answer (score 3):

To display the user meta data in the User's page, you need the filters `manage_users_custom_column` and `manage_users_columns`: [Sortable Custom Columns in User Panel (users.php)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/27518)

And to add the fields in the User/Profile pages, the following (from [Checkboxes in registration form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/87261)):

```
// PROFILE
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'user_field_wpse_87261' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_profile_fields_87261' );

// USER EDIT
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'user_field_wpse_87261' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_profile_fields_87261' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It lead to something I find a bit more simple and I'd like to hear your thoughts on it. Also, thanks for letting me know about show_user_profile & edit_user_profile. Great to know. Cheers!